# How to optimize it, (ASCII Art N)

Tags: java

I solved the problem, but I think it's too complicated. I want to make it simple, but I want to know if there are any parts that can be easily reduced from the level of difficulty used in the source code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("type odd number");
  int input = sc.nextInt();

  for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
      System.out.print("N");
      if (input == 1) {
          continue;
      }
      for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
      if (i == 0) {
          //System.out.print("");
      } else if(i != input - 1) {
          System.out.print("N");
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < input - 2 - i; j++) {
          System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.print("N");
      System.out.println();
  }
}
```

if input 1
output is

```
N
```

if input 5
output is

```
N   N
NN  N
N N N
N  NN
N   N
```

first i try delete
`if (i == 0) {//System.out.print("");}`

but it is make
input == 3
output is

```
NN  N
N N N
N   N
```

But I want

```
N N
NNN
N N
```

so i want how to make it simple code

Comment: There's a very important lesson to be learned here that will stick with you throughout your programming career, and it took me far too long to learn it. "Short ≠ Simple". Could you make this code shorter and fit all of the logic into one insane `for` loop that uses fancy absolute values and arithmetic tricks to do all of the logic? Yes. But no one would ever be able to read your code again, because while you made it much shorter, you also made it much more complex.

Comment: Split the code up into 2 major parts: 1) create an array of char of the right size and fill it with the result you want, 2) print the array. This makes the code readable, simple and testable.